# Amazon Beanstalk CLI Error: lib.utility, no module found

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to follow the directions given for getting a Django application up on Amazon Beanstalk, and when I run the `eb init` command, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python2.7/eb", line 17, in <module>
    from scli import core
  File "/usr/local/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python2.7/scli/core.py", line 24, in <module>
    from scli import command, cli_parse, config_file, prompt
  File "/usr/local/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python2.7/scli/command.py", line 16, in <module>
    from lib.utility import misc
ImportError: No module named utility
```

I am really unsure as to what I am failing to do or missing...

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that somewhere along this very terrible journey I downloaded the AWS Beanstalk CLI version 2.4, when I needed 2.6, in case anyone else makes this same clumsy mistake.